# Mapped superclass error when extend abstract class

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony5, php-8.1

I have some common fields in almost all tables. So I created an `AbstractEntity` class where I can add fields that are in common.

```
/**
* @MappedSuperclass
*/
abstract class AbstractEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"unsigned"=true})
     */
    protected int $id;
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime", nullable=false)
    */
    protected string $createdAt;
    
    
    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    
    public function createdAt(): string
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function setShopLocale(string $createdAt): self
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Now, I extend Abstractclass in other EntityClass

```
class Random extends AbstractEntity 
{
}
```

I am getting following error message when I try to insert record.

```
Class "App\Entity\Admin\Random" sub class of "App\Entity\Admin\AbstractEntity" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.
```

Comment: Your Random class still needs to be [annotated as an entity](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.13/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses).  And a bit off-topic but unless you are supporting legacy code then you probably want to switch to attributes.

Comment: Also off-topic but random is also a mysql key word.  It is not reserved but it's probably best to avoid such words.  It is possible that you just picked a name at, ahem, random in which case you can disregard this comment.